# Conditional Inserting Into Column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, batch-file, sql-insert

I'm writing a query that tests a certain software function. The query shows that the test passes if there is nothing returned.  This is the query:

```
INSERT INTO ResultsTable VALUES(N'$(Var1)', N'$(Var2)', $(SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE Table1.Column1 = ''), GetDate(), $(Var3));
```

How can I get the "`SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Table1.Column1 = '')`" to input a value of `PASS` if no values return or `FAIL` if anything at all is returned?

**EDIT:** To add some clarity, this query is being executed through a batch file. Var1, Var2, and Var3 all are varibles being declared in the batch script and pulled into this query.

I have a line that looks like this in the batch script.

```
sqlcmd -S SERVER -D DATABASE -v Var1 = "!Variable1!" Var2 = "%Variable2%"
Var3 = "!Variable3!" -i "\\path\to\the\query.sql"
```

where the query at the top is located in the file "query.sql"

**2nd EDIT:** Its probably important to add that there are multiple queries in the query.sql file that is being executed in my batch script.

I feel like its not going to be as simple as writing a bunch of queries separated by semicolons `;` (I know from the answers that the syntax isn't correct, its just to demonstrate a point)

```
INSERT INTO ResultsTable VALUES(N'$(Var1)', N'$(Var2)', $(SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE Table1.Column1 = ''), GetDate(), $(Var3));   

INSERT INTO ResultsTable VALUES(N'$(Var1)', N'$(Var2)',
$(SELECT q1.Column1, q1.Column2, q1.Column3, q2.Column4, q1.Column5-
q2.Column6 AS placeholdername1
FROM (SELECT Table3.Column1, Table3.Column2, count(*) AS placeholdername2
    FROM Table3
    GROUP BY Table3.Column1, Table3.Column2) AS q1 INNER JOIN
  (SELECT Table4.Column1, Table4.Column2,
      count(*) AS placeholdername3
    FROM Table4 INNER JOIN
      Table5 ON Table4.Columnname=
        Table5.id
    GROUP BY
      Table5.Columm1, Table5.Column2) AS
    q2 ON q1.Column1= q2.Column1 AND q1.Column2= q2.Column2
WHERE q1.Column2 - q2.Column2> 1), GetDate(), $(Var3));
```

*Please ignore all placeholder values such as column1, table3, etc because they are all placeholders and I didn't bother to ensure that they were consistent.*

Each of these queries should be dumping the results into the Results table that have columns organized like so:

```
|  Var1  |  Var2  |  Result  |  DateRun  |  Var3  |
|        |        |          |           |        |
```

Answer (score 1):

WEll first you can't use a values clause if you want to have a select. And never ever do an insert without specifying the fields you are inserting to.

```
Insert into ResultsTable (field1, field2, field3, field4, field5)
Select @var1, @var2, case when count(*) = 0 then'Fail' else 'Pass' end, getdate(), @var3
from Table1
WHERE Table1.Column1 = ''
```

Comment: Will this format work if I'm executing the query from a batch file? The Var1, Var2 are variables that are declared in the batch file. Even more specifically, the select statement is pulling values from Table1 but the other variables are declared from other places.

Comment: If they are correctly declared as SQL server variables it will work. I don't understand what you mean about running the SQL in a batch file. Perhaps you could give more description of what you are trying to do.

Comment: I'm using `sqlcmd` function for batch scripting to execute the query from a batch script. I made an edit to try and clarify.

Comment: I've tried to add significant detail but I'm getting an error everytime I try to submit the edits so I'll hopefully succeed when I try again later.